# C# - How to parametrize SQL query with MySqlAdapter

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, select, prepared-statement

I'm trying to run a SQL query using MySqlAdapter so it returns the data in a DataTable.

I'm having troubles with the parametrization. Basically it doesn't return anything and it should be returning  2 rows.

I have this code:

```
        using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(CONSTANTS.dbCONNECTSTRING))
        {
            string sqlQuery = $"SELECT * FROM tfg_bcovi.User where userName= '@userName'";
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(sqlQuery, connection);
            command.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@userName", userCtrl.UserName));

            MySqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(command);

            DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
            dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);

            DataTable dtResults = dataSet.Tables[0];           
        }
```

I checked and userCtrl.UserName have the correct value so I'm asuming something is wrong with parametrization.

The problem as I said before, is that dtResults ends up empty when it whould have at least 2 rows. I checked running the query in SQL.

[image: SQL response]

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the single quotes around the parameter. Your drive handles that for you already.

This:

```
string sqlQuery = $"SELECT * FROM tfg_bcovi.User where userName= '@userName'";
```

Should be:

```
string sqlQuery = $"SELECT * FROM tfg_bcovi.User where userName= @userName";
```